# How to use the onerror event?

Tags: smart-contract, deferred-transactions

If a deferred transaction fails for whatever reason, it triggers an onerror event, which can be captured as follows:

```
void apply_onerror(const onerror& error )
{
  print("What can I do with this?\n");
}

void mycontract::apply(account_name contract, account_name act)
{
  switch(act)
  {
    case N(onerror):
    if( contract == N(eosio) )
    {
      apply_onerror( onerror::from_current_action() );
    }
  }
}
```

How can one use this `apply_onerror` function to debug or re-execute the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

To resend failed transaction you have to unpack it from `onerror` struct and resend it.

```
transaction failed_tx = error.unpack_sent_trx();
failed_tx.send(tx_id, self);
```

see also [proxy contract](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/proxy/proxy.cpp#L81)